# Add Data For Two Month IN MDX Query for certain Account

Tags: mdx

I want to add value for certain account member for months
for example A1 has 10 value in Apr and it has 20 value in May but the result should be  30 for May 
What would the simple query for that 
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a running total? http://dinesql.blogspot.com/2014/02/analysis-services-calculating-running.html?m=1

Comment: Where do you want to add it? Inside the cube or inside a report? Also, why should be 30 for May? Where is this rule set?

Comment: hi , thanks for the response,i want to add in the cube for Example A1->May -> would contanins 30 as (10 form Apr , and 20 of it own )

Answer (score 0):

I think if you always want the current month displayed plus the previous month then this is a start for you:

```
Aggregate(
    [Date].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1) :
    [Date].[Month].CURRENTMEMBER
)
```